How to draw dynamical systems fixed point stability as in Strogatz's book
I would like to reproduce some scheme of Strogatz book with tiks or ps-plot. I've tried the whole afternoon and there is always something that goes wrong.
My code is
 \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
     clip=false,
     xmin=0,xmax=9,
     xlabel= $x$,
     ylabel=,
     ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
     axis lines=middle,
     %axis x line=middle,
     %axis y line=left,
%     axis x line=middle,
     xtick={0, 3.14, 6.28},
     xticklabels={$0$,$\pi$,$2\pi$}
     ]
      \addplot[domain=0:8,samples=200,blue]{sin(deg(x))}node[left,pos=1.1]{$\sin x$};
     
    \end{axis}
\draw  node[fill=black,circle]{} (0,0)
 
  \end{tikzpicture}

However, it doesn't put the node on the right place.

I think it would help if we could see one of those images.

please make your code a complete small document that produces some output and also show an image of the desired output.

Like this??

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
     clip=false,
     xmin=0,xmax=9,
     xlabel= $x$,
     ylabel=,
     ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
     axis lines=middle,
     %axis x line=middle,
     %axis y line=left,
%     axis x line=middle,
     xtick={0, 3.14, 6.28},
     xticklabels={$0$,$\pi$,$2\pi$}
     ]
      \addplot[domain=0:8,samples=200,blue]{sin(deg(x))}
        node[pos=1,right]{$\sin x$}
        node[pos=0,fill=black, circle]{};

    \end{axis}

     % \draw  node[fill=black,circle]{} (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

If you draw outside the axis environment it uses a different coordinate system...

If you make it black and white it will be very similar to Strogatz book, which if am not mistaken was also the author of The Joy of TeX!
